# How to pass the datastore value to javascript? i need to get data from the gae datastore and need to pass javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

am working with GAE using webapp2, python. 
Now am working in google map using gae. Successfully done with multiple locations.

```
This is my JavaScript:
======================
<script type="text/javascript">
    var USER_POSITION;
    var DESTINATION_MARKER;
    var ALL_MARKERS = [];

    var coordinateArray = [
        {coordinates: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9345494,77.6115174), id: "forum", title: "Forum", address_details: Bengaluru<br/>Karnataka-560095"},
        {coordinates: new google.maps.LatLng(12.973584,77.611293), id: "central", title: "Central", address_details: Bengaluru<br/>Karnataka-560001"},
        {coordinates: new google.maps.LatLng(12.956534,77.701239), id: "busstop", title: "Marathahalli", address_details: Bengaluru<br/>Karnataka-560037"}
    ];
</script>
```

Here am using hardcode values. But i need to pass my datastore values.
How do i pass those datastore values to my javascript.

```
This is my DBModel:
====================
class MapModel(db.Model):
 Lattitude=db.StringProperty()
 Landitude=db.StringProperty()
 Id=db.StringProperty()
 Title=db.StringProperty()
 Address=db.StringProperty()
```

Kindly provide some example code.

## My.js:

var mapProperty = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("example"), myOptions);

```
        for(var i in coordinateArray ) {
        var id = coordinateArray[i]['id'];
        var title = coordinateArray[i]['title'];
        var position = coordinateArray[i]['coordinates'];
        var address_details = coordinateArray[i]['address_details'];

        var boxText = [
                    '<div class="info_box">',
                        ..info details..
                    '</div>'
                    ].join(" ");

        var markerOptions = {
            animation: markerAnimation,
            position: coordinateArray[i]['coordinates'],
            icon: markerImage,
            map: mapProperty,
            html: boxText,
            id: id
        };
```

Comment: you can send them down as the page is rendered or you can get the page to ask for them via e.g. an ajax request

Comment: hi   Paul Collingwood  am using javascript request. i added my My.js code.. Please check.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - it either works or does not, if it does not what is the problem seen? I can't check it because I don't know what it's *supposed* to do. Anyway, these days I'm using Dart :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [webapp2 templates](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html) to pass the data to your HTML page.

Python Code:

```
coordinates = MapModel.all()

template_values = {
    'coordinates': coordinates
}    
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'YourFile.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

In HTML Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var USER_POSITION;
    var DESTINATION_MARKER;
    var ALL_MARKERS = [];

    var coordinateArray = [
        {% for cord in coordinates %}
            {coordinates: new google.maps.LatLng({{cord.Lattitude}},{{cord.Landitude}}), id: "{{cord.id}}", title: "{{cord.title}}", address_details: "{{cord.Address}}"},
        {% endfor %}

    ];
</script>
```